# Feature selection for data with both continuous and categorical features?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection

How do I perform feature selection when I have both numerical and categorical features? Is it common to partition the features and explore correlation separately (e.g. select out my categorical feature and use Chi-square, then select my continuous and use ANOVA?)

Answer (score 0):

In general - No. If you use information gain for feature selection, you first need to transform your continuous attributes into nominal attributes via discretization. The number of nominal values of an attribute can greatly affect the information gain - since the more nominal values you have, the greater the chance to explain the target variable. Make sure you have roughly the same number of values for each attribute, and that you are using information gain ratio which normalizes the information gain with respect to the number of values and their probability.

Comment: Hi  thank you for your answer. however, I don't get it here about information gain because I am talking about Chi-square and ANOVA methods, given that I have a classification problem with mixed both numerical and categorical features. Could you explain what do you mean by information gain?  Also, if we do discretization, isn't it going to convert the continuous attributes into ordinal attributes? Sorry I ama beginner this field.